# How to get the working directory after performing hg convert on perforce repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

I did the hg convert on remote perforce repository and created a Mercurial repository on my Linux box.

I can see there is nothing in my working directory, all files resided under the `.hg/` folder.

How can I make my work directory to start working on these files?
I tried `hg update` to get all files on root level to become working dir, but could not succeed.

```
/my-hgrepo
      .hg/store/data/..    [whole files are kept under this folder]
      [no working directory]
```

How can I get my files over here to start working?

What can I do now? Without getting my working directory doing `hg convert` on perforce repo is useless for me?

Comment: An `hg update` should be all that is required to check out the latest revision into your working directory.  What happened when you tried that?

Comment: I get the below message on command prompt. ( 0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved) Actually I have performed following steps after hg convert opertaion. first hg tag v..., then hg tip, then hg tags, then hg update. But did not get my work dir after this.

Comment: hg tag probably have created a new revision, which is not tip, check hg heads, and explicitely update to the "good" rev.

Comment: I 've checked with "hg heads" commands, It is showing the newly created 'tag information' with details: (changeset, user, tag, date summary). Tried with "hg update tip" and "hg update <new tag version>" but both are not working.

Comment: what does 'hg manifest -r tip' get you?  If the answer is nothing then you have no committed files in your tip revision.

Answer (score 5):

Try `hg update tip`  that should get you the latest in your working dir.

Comment: I tried with "hg update tip" but its not working. same results is returned (0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved).